# Returning to the start of a program when user input doesn't meet certain criteria

Tags: java, math

I've written a little program that will add 2 matrices together. Each matrix must have the same number of rows and columns. Is there a neat way of returning the user to the start of the program again if they enter for example a 2x2 + 3x3?

```
   import java.util.*;
   import javax.swing.*;

   public class MatrixAdd {
    public static void main (String[] args)
      {

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows you want in Matrix 1 => ");
        Scanner stdio = new Scanner (System.in);
        int rowA = stdio.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want in Matrix 1 => ");
        int columnA = stdio.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows you want in Matrix 2 => ");
        int rowB = stdio.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want in Matrix 2 => ");
        int columnB = stdio.nextInt();

        if (rowA != rowB || columnA != columnB)
        {
            System.out.println("Matrix 1 and Matrix 2 must have same number of rows and columns");
        }

        int arrayA[][] = new int[rowA][columnA];

            for(int i = 0; i < rowA; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < columnA; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter element for row " + (i+1) + " column "+ (j+1) + " of Matrix 1 => ");
                    arrayA[i][j] = stdio.nextInt();
                }
            }

        int arrayB[][] = new int[rowB][columnB];

            for(int i = 0; i < rowB; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < columnB; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter element for row " + (i+1) + " column "+ (j+1) + " of Matrix 2 => ");
                    arrayB[i][j] = stdio.nextInt();
                }
            }


        int arrayC[][] = new int[rowA][columnA];

        for(int i = 0; i < rowB; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < columnB; j++)
            {
                arrayC[i][j] = arrayA[i][j] + arrayB[i][j];
            }
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < rowA; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("[");

            for(int j = 0; j < columnA; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + arrayC[i][j]);

            }

            System.out.print(" ] " + "\n");

        }   


    }

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do...while(CONDITION)` loop, with `CONDITION` being, the two matrices having the same size. You should just transform your few lines of code in:

```
do
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows you want in Matrix 1 => ");
    Scanner stdio = new Scanner (System.in);
    int rowA = stdio.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want in Matrix 1 => ");
    int columnA = stdio.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows you want in Matrix 2 => ");
    int rowB = stdio.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want in Matrix 2 => ");
    int columnB = stdio.nextInt();

    if (rowA != rowB || columnA != columnB)
    {
        System.out.println("Matrix 1 and Matrix 2 must have same number of rows and columns");
    }
}while(rowA != rowB || columnA != columnB)
```

Answer (score 0):

put all the logic in another function, let's name it `DoSomething` that return a boolean and just do

```
while(!DoSomething());
```

and make `DoSomething` in the case of two matrix with different sized, return `false`

full code:

```
   import java.util.*;
   import javax.swing.*;

   public class MatrixAdd {

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
        while(DoSomething() == false){}
   }

   private static boolean DoSomething()
      {

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows you want in Matrix 1 => ");
        Scanner stdio = new Scanner (System.in);
        int rowA = stdio.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want in Matrix 1 => ");
        int columnA = stdio.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows you want in Matrix 2 => ");
        int rowB = stdio.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want in Matrix 2 => ");
        int columnB = stdio.nextInt();

        if (rowA != rowB || columnA != columnB)
        {
            System.out.println("Matrix 1 and Matrix 2 must have same number of rows and columns");
             return false; /// MY EDIT OF THE FUNCTION
        }

        int arrayA[][] = new int[rowA][columnA];

            for(int i = 0; i < rowA; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < columnA; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter element for row " + (i+1) + " column "+ (j+1) + " of Matrix 1 => ");
                    arrayA[i][j] = stdio.nextInt();
                }
            }

        int arrayB[][] = new int[rowB][columnB];

            for(int i = 0; i < rowB; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < columnB; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter element for row " + (i+1) + " column "+ (j+1) + " of Matrix 2 => ");
                    arrayB[i][j] = stdio.nextInt();
                }
            }


        int arrayC[][] = new int[rowA][columnA];

        for(int i = 0; i < rowB; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < columnB; j++)
            {
                arrayC[i][j] = arrayA[i][j] + arrayB[i][j];
            }
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < rowA; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("[");

            for(int j = 0; j < columnA; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + arrayC[i][j]);

            }

            System.out.print(" ] " + "\n");

        }   

        return true; /// MY EDIT OF THE FUNCTION
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
while(!isValid(allInputs)) {
    // Ask to enter inputs
}
// do something with valid inputs

...
private boolean isValid(MyTypes inputs) {
    // are my inputs valid?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it infinitely like a calculator I suggest do something like below

```
     while(true) {
         System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows you want in Matrix 1 => ");
         Scanner stdio = new Scanner (System.in);
         int rowA = stdio.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want in Matrix 1 => ");
         int columnA = stdio.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows you want in Matrix 2 => ");
         int rowB = stdio.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want in Matrix 2 => ");
         int columnB = stdio.nextInt();

         int decide = (rowA+columnA) - (rowB+columnB);
         switch(decide) {
             case 0 : //your code logic;
                 break;
             default:
                 System.out.println("rows and cols of both matrices must be equal");
         }
     }
```